# When opening Xcode looping authentication when installing additional components

Tags: xcode, macos, security, installation, startup

On OS X 10.10.1 and with Xcode 6.1.1 on Xcode startup, I am presented with a dialog box:

"Install additional required components?
Xcode requires additional components to support running and debugging. Choose install to add required components"

If I select "Quit" Xcode quits, which is no good to me.

If I select "Install" I'm presented with dialog "Xcode wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this." When I authenticate, I'm left with the original dialog above. It is an endless loop that prevents me from using Xcode.

`id -p` in terminal returns:

> groups staff com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 everyone local accounts
>   _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _appstore _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh

```
[MM-laptop]~$xcode-select -p
```

in terminal returns

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Xcode has been deleted and freshly installed.

I do not know how to diagnose and  correct the problem despite all the research. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, and it was fixed by starting Xcode from command line with "installComponents" option.

`$ /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -installComponents`

> then, the same dialog box asking "install". Type the password, will take just minutes finish the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem in Xcode11 GM fix by putting below command in command line tool:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode11 -installComponents
```

In my case my xcode name is Xcode11 you can change the name according.